# Maclaurin series expansion of order 4 of a composite function

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

We are asked to find the Maclaurin expansion of order 4 for $$f(x) = \sqrt{1+\sin(x)}$$
Here's what the correction sheet says:
$$\sqrt{1+\sin(x)} = \left(1+\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ + x^4\epsilon(x)\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
This makes sense, since the Taylor expansion at x=$0$ (a.k.a the Maclaurin series) of order $4$ of "$1+\sin(x)$" is "$1+\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ + x^4\epsilon(x)\right)$". However, it is the next step I cannot seem to get: $$ \left(1+\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ + x^4\epsilon(x)\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 1\ + \frac{1}{2}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ + x^4\epsilon(x)\right)- \frac{1}{8}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ + x^4\epsilon(x)\right)^{2} + \frac{1}{16} \left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ + x^4\epsilon(x)\right)^{3} - \frac{5}{128}\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}\ + x^4\epsilon(x)\right)^4$$
From here, I know how to finish the exercise.

Comment: Please use `\sin` to write $\sin$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the **Binomial Series**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is 
\begin{align}
f(x) 
&= \sqrt{1+\mathbb{sin(x)}} \\
&= \sin\dfrac{x}{2}+\cos\dfrac{x}{2} \\
&= \left(\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)-\dfrac{1}{3!}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^3+\cdots\right)+\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2!}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^2+\cdots\right) \\
&= 1+\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)-\dfrac{1}{2!}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^2-\dfrac{1}{3!}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)^3+\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: nice trick and much faster to get the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

MacLaurin series for $\sqrt{1+t}$ is

$1 + t/2 - t^2/8 + t^3/16 - (5 t^4)/128+O(t^5)\quad(*)$

For $\sin x$ is

$x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}+O(x^5)$

You can plug $t=x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}$ in $(*)$ and get

$$-\frac{1}{128} \cdot 5 \left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)^4+\frac{1}{16} \left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)^3-\frac{1}{8} \left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2} \left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)+1$$

Then expand just up to the $4$th power of $x$, getting

$$\sqrt{1+\sin x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{48}+\frac{x^4}{384}+O(x^5)$$